# Need help on Vlookup between two sheets between two linked columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet1 data in below format

[image]

I need VBA Code to `vlookup` in sheet2 on Group Id and Product ID in sheet1 and insert new row highlighted in yellow called BT order and populate 400 and 600 values from DMD column against Wk8 and Wk9 column which is `vlookup` value of week Num from second sheet.

[image]

```vba
Dim i As Long 

For i = 2 To Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
    If Trim(Range("E" & i).Value) = RTrim("CMT") Then 
        Rows(i + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown 
        Range("A" & i + 1 & ":D" & i + 1).Value = Range("A" & i - 1 & ":D" & i - 1).Value 
        Range("E" & i + 1).Value = "BT/Order" 
    End If 
Next i
```

Comment: like this i have multiple Group Id and Product ID

Comment: Why does data from week 2 and 3 go to weeks 8 and 9?   What have you tried, and what specific problem did you run into? Simplest approach would just be to loop over rows on sheet2 and match on Group+Product - did you try that?

Comment: weeks starts with 0,1,2 so on and corresponding values have to populate against weeks which are in columns in sheet1

Comment: here if week Num is 0 in sheet2 then wk6 column in sheet1 like wise for Week Num 1 wk7 in sheet1 ,week num 2 for wk8 in sheet1

Comment: i tried but getting difficulties in selecting ranges, i have multiple group id and product id

Comment: Always helps to get answers here if you post the code you tried...

Comment: I tried this code to insert new row BT-Order but not getting how to do vlookup .

Comment: Code : Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Trim(Range("E" & i).Value) = RTrim("CMT") Then      
         Rows(i + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
             Range("A" & i + 1 & ":D" & i + 1).Value = Range("A" & i - 1 & ":D" & i - 1).Value
          Range("E" & i + 1).Value = "BT/Order"
         
        End If
 Next i

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vba
Sub Tester()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, i2 As Long, grp, prod, amt, wk
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    i = 2
    Do While i <= ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        If Trim(ws1.Range("E" & i).Value) = RTrim("CMT") Then
            
            ws1.Rows(i + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
            ws1.Cells(i + 1, "A").Resize(1, 4).Value = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, 4).Value
            ws1.Cells(i + 1, "E").Value = "BT/Order"
            
            'current group/product id's
            grp = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value
            prod = ws1.Cells(i, "C").Value
            
            'loop sheet2 and find matches
            For i2 = 2 To ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                If ws2.Cells(i2, "A").Value = grp Then
                    If ws2.Cells(i2, "B").Value = prod Then
                        'got match - check amount and week
                        amt = ws2.Cells(i2, "D").Value
                        wk = ws2.Cells(i2, "E").Value
                        If amt > 0 Then
                            'insert amount in relevant column  
                            ws1.Cells(i + 1, "F").Offset(0, wk).Value = amt
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next i2
        
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this Thank You its working but its inserting 2 BT/Order rows values as 400 and 600

Comment: It worked for me but I only had your small sample data...

Comment: i am getting this error selection isn't valid make sure copy and paste areas don't overlaps unless they are the same size and shapes

Comment: I'm not doing any copy/paste so it's not clear exactly what you're referring to.